# Right click menu on svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I implemented a right click menu for my app using JQuery but the list is indented to the right and the entire block is about 20px below. What causes it?

I'm using this code to implement right click menu : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sachid/29xwpd2o/)

```
<svg id="canvas" class="canvas" width="1800" height="500">
  <rect class="ddd" id="ddd" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="200" fill="#D3DA7B" stroke="black"></rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add to your `<ul>`:

```
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
```

Lists (both unordered and ordered) have `padding` and `margin` set by default. So you need to clear that.

https://jsfiddle.net/29xwpd2o/3/

Comment: Got it. But what about the verticcal gap?